# syntax for ROR associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Apologies in advance for another newbie question, but the ROR syntax is just not clicking with me, I can't get my head around the shortcuts and conventions (despite reading a couple of books already!) -

I effectively copied this from a book, but I"m trying to work out what is build, create etc?

```
@cart = current_cart
product = Catalog::Product.find(params[:product_id])
Rails.logger.debug { "Value in cart id " + @cart.id.to_s }

@checkout_line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)

respond_to do |format|
  if @checkout_line_item.save...
```

The output from log is this:

```
Processing by Checkout::LineItemsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"9NH+xgDPTf/iN7RCdPd8H9rAIqWsSVB/f/rIT++Kk7M=", "product_id"=>"7"}
Created a line item
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO `checkout_carts` (`created_at`, `discounts`, `grand_total`,   `loyalty_points`, `order_date`, `subtotal`, `timestamps`, `total_tax`, `updated_at`) VALUES    ('2012-08-21 11:06:15', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-08-21 11:06:15')
(0.2ms)  COMMIT
Catalog::Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` =   7 LIMIT 1
Value in cart id 8
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/checkout/line_items_controller.rb:55:in `block in create'
app/controllers/checkout/line_items_controller.rb:54:in `create'
```

I'm guessing the problem lies with the build syntax where it builds the checkout line item, or possibly I've set up the has_many associations wrong. Is this enough for someone to help me troubleshoot? Or should I post the model declarations?

Update with models:

```
class Checkout::LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :customer_update_date, :inventory_status, :line_item_color, :line_item_description, :line_item_size, :line_item_tagline, :line_item_total, :quantity, :sku_id, :style_id, :tax, :tax_code, :timestamps, :unit_price, :product
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product, :class_name => 'Catalog::Product'
end

class Checkout::Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :discounts, :grand_total, :loyalty_points, :order_date, :subtotal, :timestamps, :total_tax

  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
end

module Catalog
  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :assoc_product,:product_id, :merch_associations, :aux_description, :buyable, :long_description, :name, :on_special, :part_number, :release_date, :short_description, :withdraw_date, :occasion
   <<clipped for brevity>>

has_many :line_items, :class_name => 'Checkout::LineItem'
...
  end
```

Can't answer my own question, but I think I got the answer:

It looks like I needed to add the cart to the build call...

this appears to have worked (I think, there's another blocking problem, but I can sort that one):

```
@cart = current_cart
product = Catalog::Product.find(params[:product_id])
Rails.logger.debug { "Value in cart id " + @cart.id.to_s }

@checkout_line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product, cart: @cart)
```

Comment: Model declarations would definitely help here. For some reason, that `build` is returning `nil`.

Comment: It's not (or shouldn't be) necessary to add `cart: @cart` because that foreign key value is automatically populated when you call `build`. There must be something else going on.

Comment: ok I think I might have solved it if that's the case anyway. Seems I had not created necessary foreign key columns in the migration for the line items table. Seems okay now, just sorting through some issues but should be sorted shortly...

Answer (score 0):

`Build` essentially creates and reserves space for a blank object. This allows you to create an associated object without saving it. The only use case I've experienced this with is a nested form where I had multiple dates for an event, so I used 5.times.build to create 5 empty date associations.